# Can't Remove Windows.Forms reference from WPF Project

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, winforms

I added `<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>` to my .NET 6.0 WPF project to use some dialog classes, and then removed it after deciding to use the `WindowsAPICodePack` instead. But the project is still behaving as if I were referencing `System.Windows.Forms`. Intellisense offers the Namespaces/Types, and `System.Windows.Forms.Analyzers` and `System.Windows.Forms.Analyzers.CSharp` show up in the Analyzers section of Solution Explorer.

However, it no longer shows up under the Frameworks section of Solution Explorer. The `<ImplicitUsings>` also stopped including the namespace.

How do I get rid of the DLL references? I've tried running "Remove unused references" and it didn't help.

Comment: Check if there is a <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.WindowsForms" /> tag and remove it.

Comment: No tags like that, no. There's nothing in the csproj that I would expect to bring in winforms.

Answer (score 0):

After my test, the Forms reference can be deleted.Please check if the steps below are consistent with yours.

1.Delete all codes and references related to Forms in the project.

```
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    ...

    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("hello");
```

2.Right-click the project and select Unload Project, then right-click the project and select Edit Project File.

3.Delete `<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>` and save the csproj file.

4.Right-click the project and select Reload Project ,then rebuild the project.

5.You could see that all references to Forms in the Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.AppWPF directory have been deleted.

[image]